# How to pause javafx class

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am building an alarm and it consists of two parts
an animated button created in `javafx` class and the engine which is created normally

what I need is whenever user press the animated button that closes the button and fire up the engine then after the engine is closed there will be some time then animated button appears again and so on
so I used ::

```
notify_me.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            new engine();
            Platform.exit();
        }
    });
```

and in order to repeat this process I used

```
Timer t = new Timer(0,new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             while(true){
                 javafx.launch(javafx.class);
                 //some extra code goes here including sleep for
                 //some time and check for engine window state
             }
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

but I am facing two problems:

1. `some extra code` isn`t implemented until platform is exited,
2. `launch()` cannot be called more than once

so how can I achieve that without using threads ?? thanks

Comment: Calling `Platform.exit` closes the application and invalidates the JavaFX thread. Even if it is theoretically possible to start a new JavaFX `Application` from the same program, it's probably highly discouraged.  

Could you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve? 

Also - have a look at [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm). `Task` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: well that while loop gives an exception when running so i dont know why platform.exit doesnt terminate it completly so i can restart it in peace what i need  is a pause and play method for that javafx class as terminating then restarting it doesnt work,neither keeping it works will run the code after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably won't get around using `Thread`s. I'd recommend not shutting down the fx application thread however. Just close all windows and show (some of) them again after the delay:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button("Hide me 5 sec");

    // prevent automatic exit of application when last window is closed
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    // timer should be a daemon (-> not prevent jvm shutdown)
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);

    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // make window reappear (needs to happen on the application thread)
                Platform.runLater(primaryStage::show);
            }
        }, 5000l);

        // hide window
        primaryStage.close();
    });

    // allow exiting the application by clicking the X
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(evt -> Platform.exit());

    primaryStage.show();
}
```